# Should the Git repository root be the same as the project root on our IDE?

Tags: git, ide, repository

I'm developing a PHP application in a IDE, and want to use Git for version control.

How should I arrange my repository layout?

Should the Git repository root be the same as the project root on our IDE, or a sub- or superdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a git repository lay out with the project name as the root, under which all your source would lie, including cron jobs, db scripts, unit tests, library code as well as the PHP source in your www root. For example:

```
projectName
|
+ cron jobs
+ db_scripts
+ libs (third party libraries)
+ php library code (e.g. database access, models, utilities etc)
+ tests
+ www_root
  |
  + images
  + etc...
  index.php
  ...
+ etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your git repository should contain everything you'd possibly want under version control.
This definitely includes your source files, but most likely does not include the compiled binaries.

Personally, I put the repository root at the root of the source folder, because these are the only files I need version control for.

Comment: I see. Let's say we are developing a Zend Framework project, we should not put our repository files under the Zend Framework Specific Folders, but, instead, on the root of the application we are atually developing. Is that it? Thanks again.

Comment: If that is all you need to distribute, yes. If there are libraries you wish to synchronize for convenience, or testing code outside this folders, chose your toot higher up. Spolto gives a good example.